# Having trouble understanding the scope of instance variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby, scope, instance-variables

I have two sets of code

```rb
@movies = ["Zoolander", "Sandlot"]

def good_movies
    @movies.each do |movie|
    puts "I love #{movie}!"
    end
end

good_movies
#I love Zoolander!
#I love Sandlot!
```

I understand of the scope of local variables, so there has to be instance variables for the code to run otherwise I would get a NameError

But when it comes to this bit

```rb
class Example
  
   @scope = "This is the scope of the class itself"

   def hello
       p @scope 
   end

 end

ex = Example.new
ex.hello 
# nil
```

Looks like the predefined instance variable cannot be accessed but I didn't get an error. It should be to do with the instantiation, but I don't know the exact reason why.
Can anyone give me some pointers on this?

Answer (score 4):

> Looks like the predefined instance variable cannot be accessed but I didn't get an error.

Accessing an undefined [instance variable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Instance+Variables) doesn't raise an exception, it just returns `nil`.

Since you define the instance variable on the class object itself, you need a method in the same [scope](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Scope) to access it, i.e. a *class method*:

```
class Example
  @scope = "This is the scope of the class itself"

  def self.hello
    p @scope
  end
end

Example.hello
#=> "This is the scope of the class itself"
```

To define a variable for your instances, use `initialize`: (so each instance has its own `@scope`)

```
class Example
  def initialize
    @scope = "This is the scope of an instance"
  end

  def hello
    p @scope
  end
end

ex = Example.new
ex.hello
#=> "This is the scope of an instance"
```

You could also access the instance's class via [`Object#class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Object.html#class-method) and its instance variable via [`instance_variable_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Object.html#instance_variable_get-method):

```
class Example
  @scope = "This is the scope of the class itself"

  def hello
    p self.class.instance_variable_get(:@scope)
  end
end

ex = Example.new
ex.hello
#=> "This is the scope of the class itself"
```

Apparently this violates any encapsulation efforts. If you really wanted to do this, you should define a getter:

```
class Example
  @scope = "This is the scope of the class itself"
  class << self
    attr_reader(:scope)
  end

  def hello
    p self.class.scope
  end
end

ex = Example.new
ex.hello
#=> "This is the scope of the class itself"

Example.scope
#=> "This is the scope of the class itself"
```

Comment: This is absolutely amazing!! Thank you so very much!